# How to stream videos I own to an android device?

Tags: video, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a DLNA enabled media player for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/is-there-a-dlna-enabled-media-player-for-android)
>   [Video streaming from PC to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11885/video-streaming-from-pc-to-android)

I've largely been an iPhone/iPad person. I am looking at getting a Kindle Fire or Nook color. I really just want to be able to stream video from my already huge collection of movies that I have on hand. I have used the Boxee and Airplayit applications for PC/iPad/iPhone.... Anything like that for Android or will I be stuck encoding and transferring?

Comment: Also note that UPnP and DLNA are the technology standards that look after streaming media to devices on a home network, see this previous question [Is there a DLNA enabled media player for Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I favour [Subsonic](http://subsonic.org) for my media streaming, which has [a native Android client](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.sourceforge.subsonic.androidapp&hl=en) (along with iPhone and more).

Comment: Subsonic looks awesome; except the video playback on Android is crap. It loads up an HTML page with a flash player in it? Pretty bad quality.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with quality myself, but I stream video to my phone and not a tablet - screen size may make a diff there.