# Can we connect VGA from PC directly into android

Tags: android-pc

I want to use google cardboard as VR monitor from PC with my phone. So I want to know is it possible to just connect from my PC VGA to android USB port and override android screen

Comment: Might point you in right direction: **[USB to VGA adapter Android](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+vga+adapter+android)**

Comment: @GokulNC Thanks but that opposite. I already try to search and most of them is show android to projector, not vga to phone

Comment: Have you looked at non-cabled options like screen streaming and sharing over wifi? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11885/video-streaming-from-pc-to-android

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible through VGA cable, But you can try Desktop steaming apps.

Comment: That option sure possible but it slow that's why I try to find other way around